# Having trouble with delaunay, minimum spanning tree and astar for level generation

Tags: a-star, gdscript, minimum-spanning-tree, delaunay, godot4

I've got a script im trying to use to generate game levels using gdscript. I place some rooms add doors based on pre-defined values to a gridmap then try to calculate the delaunay triangulation and minimum spanning tree to connect the doors with hallway using astar

I can place the rooms fine but the hallways don't seem to be lining up with the rooms properly, and if I increase the number of rooms the hallways are just nonsensical spaghetti.

I've tried printing the door locations and various other variables along the way to try and work out where its going wrong but I really don't understand to the core what the astar, delaunay and mst's actually do at a finite level only the basic idea and it's hard as you can't really visualise it.

I'm hoping some can shed some light on where im going wrong

https://github.com/shaunzorr/DungeonGeneratorTest